# Display clarity issue in Ubuntu 20.04 with Intel Graphics Drivers

Tags: drivers, display, display-resolution

Recently I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Dektop machine. Though I am getting a display resolution 1920x1080, there seems to be some issue with the display driver. The fonts are not very clear, showing the staircase effect. [image: Please see the reference picture attached].

The command `sudo lshw -c video` gave the following results.

```
display description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:127 memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I have tried the solution discussed  [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2377324). But could not get any improvement.
How can I install the proper driver so that I can get a smooth display?

Comment: Do you have scaling enabled? Installed/selected a different font? What connection... vga, dvi, or hdmi? There is no better driver for your config.

Comment: @heynnema  I have not enabled scaling as I read that it may further decrease the quality. I am using the default font. Connection is through VGA.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure scaling is disabled, and that you're using the standard fonts/theme.

Open `Tweaks` (gnome-tweaks) and try and change the Hinting  and Antialiasing settings...

[image]

Comment: As per your suggestion, I installed tweaks and changed Hinting to None, which resulted in a slight improvement in the Fonts. Other combinations on Hinting and Antialiasing didn't work. But the overall performance is same....less clarity on the icons, sharp-less images. I doubt the driver itself. But it is accepting higher resolutions (1920x1080)!

Comment: @Soo I would have suspected that higher hinting, and subpixel antialiasing, would have been better. However, if your eye sees improvement in different settings, who's going to argue! It's the best you'll get with a VGA connection.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But my problem still persists!

Comment: @Soo The only way that it's going to get better is to 1) try a different/better VGA cable, 2) use a DVI or HDMI connection.